# Dbcontext List is taking long time to execute

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a generic repository and and a method

```
public List<employee> List()
                {
                    return _dbContext.Set<employee>().Where(x => x.Status == "Active")ToList();
                }
```

This call is taking 2 to 5 minutes if I have 2000 records

If I am using EF directly with out repository it is working very fast

```
var p = from emp in context.Inboxes where employee.Status == "Active" select employee;
```

How I can improve performance of repository collection?

Comment: You have 2 different queries here for a start. Secondly, the second one isn't executed until you loop through it.

Comment: If the first call takes 2 to 5 minutes for only 2000 records there must be a lot more going on. I suspect that the query triggers massive lazy loading afterwards. Check the executed queries.

Comment: Add an index on `Status` property could be a good way too